# Laravel redirect after Login issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

#### Problem Statement:

I'm trying modify Multiple Authentication to authenticate different user by using Multiple Models, route, guards and Controller.

The user is redirected to `teacher/home` instead of `v2/teacher/home`

> `teacher/home` is earlier route whereas `v2/teacher/home` is new modified route.

---

#### Below is Directory Structure

```
- app/
    - Http/
        - Controllers/
            - Teacher/
                - LoginController.php
                - RegisterController.php
            - Student/
                - LoginController.php
                - RegisterController.php
        - Middleware/
            - RedirectIfTeacher.php
            - RedirectIfStudent.php
            - RedirectIfNotTeacher.php
            - RedirectIfNotStudent.php
            
    - Models/
        - Teacher.php
        - Student.php
```

---

#### Files & Configuration

I will share the steps and code here to find where the problem is:

- I created the necessary guards, providers and password brokers
- I created the custom model
- I created the custom middlewares
- I created the necessary routes and controllers

`App\Http\Controllers\v2\Teacher\Auth\LoginController.php`

```
    use AuthenticatesUsers, LogsoutGuard {
        LogsoutGuard::logout insteadof AuthenticatesUsers;
    }

    public $redirectTo = '/v2/teacher/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('teacher.guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('v2.teacher.auth.login');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('teacher');
    }
```

`routes\web.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2', 'as' => 'v2.'], function (){
   
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'teacher', 'as' => 'teacher.'], function (){

    Route::get('login', 'v2\Teacher\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'v2\Teacher\Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login.post');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:teacher'], function (){
      Route::get('home', 'v2\Teacher\HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

`app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'check' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotCheck::class,
        'check.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfCheck::class,

        'teacher' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfTeacher::class,
        'teacher.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotTeacher::class,

        'student' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfStudent::class,
        'student.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotStudent::class,
```

`App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfTeacher.php`

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'teacher')
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { 
            return redirect('v2/teacher/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

> `Auth::guard($guard)->check()` returning `false`

`config\auth.php`

```
    'guards' => [
        'teacher' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'teachers',
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],


    'providers' => [
        'teacher' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Teacher::class,
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
        ],
```

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan cache:clear` or any other cache clearing commands with artisan? Editing config files usually requires this. :)

Comment: @Digitalam, I've tried artisan cache command.

Comment: look like the issue is  if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())  return true then you should redirect to next request or else logout page or forbidden page.I can see the question is auth guard returning false issue or you are saying it wont redirect to v2/teacher/home

Comment: @JohnLobo `Auth::guard($guard)->check()` is returning `false`